# Dockerized version of Redis has a problem of configuration

Tags: docker, redis

I'm following the steps explained here:

- https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-use-the-redis-docker-official-image/
- https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file like this:

```
version: '3'

services:

  backend:
    build: server/
    image: cno/api
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: "production"
    ports:
      - "9114:9114"
    networks:
      - cnonetwork
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    depends_on:
      - redis

  redis:
    build: redis/
    image: cno/redis
    networks:
      - cnonetwork

  frontend:
    build: client/
    image: cno/client
    networks:
      - cnonetwork

  rp:
    build: reverse-proxy/
    image: cno/rp
    depends_on:
      - frontend
      - backend
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - cnonetwork


networks:
  cnonetwork:
```

And my `Dockerfile` of Redis is here:

```
FROM redis
COPY redis.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
CMD [ "redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf" ]
```

The `redis.conf` being the same suggested in the documentation (https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/unstable/redis.conf). My container exits with this error:

```
*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR (Redis 7.0.9) ***
Reading the configuration file, at line 415
>>> 'locale-collate ""'
Bad directive or wrong number of arguments
```

I have the same error when I change the config file:

```
*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR (Redis 7.0.9) ***
Reading the configuration file, at line 415
>>> 'locale-collate "en_US.UTF-8"'
Bad directive or wrong number of arguments
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It will be easier to diagnose this if you can post the contents of your `redis.conf`.

Comment: I put the link but it's the one of the documentation, I changed nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using the `unstable` version of the `redis.conf` file with the Redis 7.0.9 release of `redis-server`.

This version does not yet appear to support the `locale-collate` configuration parameter, which is probably why it errors when faced with a config file that contains this.

Here's the code for the config file for 7.0.9 tag which doesn't mention `locale-collate`:

https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/7.0.9/src/config.c

I'd advise using the 7.0.9 version of the config file, or if you really need this parameter then compile an unstable version of `redis-server`.

Here's the 7.0.9 config file:

https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/7.0.9/redis.conf

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. Strange that the documentation suggests an "unstable" version.

Answer (score 0):

Always refer to `https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/<redis_version>/redis.conf`. For example if you are using 7.0.11 refer to `https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/7.0.11/redis.conf`. In `7.0.11` the following section is not even defined.

```
# Set the local environment which is used for string comparison operations, and
# also affect the performance of Lua scripts. Empty String indicates the locale
# is derived from the environment variables.
locale-collate ""
```